# Изменить название и путь картинки заданные в HTML через JS

Tags: javascript, html

В JS Задан массив

```
const initialCards = [
    {
        name: 'Архыз',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg'
    },
```

В HTML уже есть своя картинка со своим названием

````
<section class="elements">
            <div class="elements__element">
                <img src="./img/Karachaevsk.jpg" alt="Карачаевск" class="elements__photo">
                <div class="elements__group">
                    <h2 class="elements__title">Карачаевск</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="elements__like"></button>
                </div>
            </div> ```
````

Нужно сделать так что при загрузке страницы картинка и название html менялись на JS. Логику вижу такую как:

1. Запросить и сделать запрошенные атрибуты src и elements__title массивом например: Array.from(element.getAttribute('src') и присвоить ему значение link
2. Запросить elements__title и заменить текст на значение из массива name.
3. И выполнить функцию присваивания атрибуту src и name новый путь из другого массива.

И таких 6 карточек (6 картинок и 6 названий).

И вот вроде с логикой более все понять запросить из html картинку и название сделать массивом, и и заменить элементы массива из html на js, но как реализовать уже не знаю что смотреть два дня сижу пробую разными способами например через InnerHtml но тоже не получается, одно из условия нельзя добавлять изменения в css.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема именно с выводом массива в HTML? Если да, то метод array.map() может помочь.
Если уже есть массив объектов с полями title и link, то можно сделать так, присвоить блоку с классом "elements__element" какой-нибудь id, например "elementDiv" и потом обратиться к нему в методе мар():

```
const initialCards = [
    {
        name: 'Архыз',
        link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg'
    }, ];


elementDiv.innerHTML = initialCards.map(item => `
   <img src="${item.link}" alt="${item.name}" class="elements__photo">
   <div class="elements__group">
      <h2 class="elements__title">${item.name}</h2>
      <button type="button" class="elements__like"></button>
   </div>`).join("");
```

Comment: Супер хоть уже с мертвой точки сдвинулся, спасибо) Теперь получается история такая. У меня таких 6 элементов, если я задаяю id одному элементу elements__element. То получается в один блок заходят все 6 элементов из массива. Если id даю каждому elements__element то ничего не происходит. Вопрос теперь как сформировать это все что бы. 6 заданных карточек в html меняли свои значение на 6 элементов массива заданные в JS ?) Добавить .forEach что бы пройти по всем элементам массива?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтоб изначально отображались 6 элементов с одним набором имен и картинок, а потом они менялись на другие?

Comment: Да получается при загрузке сайта даны 6 карточек (картинка + название) которые заданные в HTML мне нужно что бы данные карточки заменили свои элементы (картинка + название) на элементы которые заданны в массиве JS [ https://kreshman.github.io/mesto/ ]

Comment: Понял. тогда можно убрать id у div и сделать что-то наподобие:
let section = document.querySelector('section');
section.innerHTML = initialCards.map(item => `
 <div class="elements__element">
    <img src="${item.link}" alt="${item.name}" class="elements__photo">
    <div class="elements__group">
       <h2 class="elements__title">${item.name}</h2>
       <button type="button" class="elements__like"></button>
    </div>
</div>`).join("");

Comment: Я же могу взять в const elementsElement = document.querySelector('elements__element') - так как помимо этих секций у меня ещё другие есть? Или без разницы он буде проходить по секциями где есть div class="elements__element"?

Comment: Если у вас несколько секций и вы не хотите менять содержимое всех, то лучше присвоить id нужной секции и изменять ее содержимое согласно вышеуказанному. А это - elementsElement = document.querySelector('elements__element'), у вас не сработает, потому что querySelector обращается к тегу, а не к классу.

Comment: Понял, сделал как у вас и получилось так что, картинки с названием  не заменились а добавились, то есть теперь в начале страницы 1 столбом 6 картинок с js а потом ниже в 3 ряда 2 строчки картинки из html Я бы загрузил картинку но в комментариях не могу, могу отправить в telegram )

Comment: Ну, тут уже нужно с флексом играться. Или вы что-то не так указали. Потому что innerHTML меняет содержимое тега, к которму он вызван

Comment: Добавил id секции и получилось вот так: 
elementsSwap.innerHTML = initialCards.map(item => `
<div class="elements__element"> 
    <img src="${item.link}" alt="${item.name}" class="elements__photo"> 
    <div class="elements__group"> 
        <h2 class="elements__title">${item.name}</h2> <button type="button" class="elements__like"></button> 
    </div> 
</div>`).join("");

Нигде не могу найти четкое определение .join(""); можете объяснить своими словами если не сложно?) А так спасибо большое выручили два дня сижу с мертвой точки сдвинутся не могу!) Лайк

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. А метод join("") возвращает элементы массива или объекты в одну строку. В скобках указывается, чем разделять эти элементы. В вашем случае в скобках пусто, потому что в виде разделителей уже выступают теги.

Comment: Можете подсказать с какой документацией лучше ознакомиться что бы было более ясно по данной тематике, а то надоело вечно спрашивать и чувствовать себя "тупым"))))

Comment: Думаю, learn.javascript подойдет

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите я могу как нибудь если потребуется у вас ещё помощи попросить если нужно будет?)

Comment: Увы, я и сам учусь, и многие вещи пока не знаю. Пишите тут)

Comment: Добрый день ещё раз, подскажи насколько я понял innerHTML не очень безопасный способ, а можно точно такое же реализовать через template?

Comment: Привет. Этого, увы, я сказать не могу( Не знаком с таким способом.